# ‎Find some examples which have this property $‎\lim‎_{n\to{‎\infty‎}}f(n+x)\neq\lim‎_{n\to{‎\infty‎}}f(n)$‎.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Let ‎‎$‎‎f$ be a‎ ‎real ‎function. Can anyone help me giving an ‎example with the following property

‎‎‎$‎‎‎\lim‎_{n\to{‎\infty‎}}f(n+x)\neq\lim‎_{n\to{‎\infty‎}}f(n) \quad; n\in\mathbb{N}$‎

for this purpose, I think that I should follow the functions with the following property‎
‎$$‎‎f(a+b)=f(a)f(b) $$‎‎‎‎‎
It is same as exponential function but it doesn't work.

Comment: Careful. Are we assuming these limits exist? Must they be finite?

Comment: @Theo Bendi, Yes, we assume that they must have finite limits

Comment: @ dxiv, yes $n$ is an integer.

Answer (score 5):

Try
$$f(x) = \sin(2\pi x).$$
Then $f(n) = 0$ for all $n$, so $\lim_{n \to \infty} f(n) = 0$. But, if we take $x = \frac{1}{4}$, then
$$\lim_{n \to \infty} f(x + n) = \lim_{n \to \infty} 1 = 1.$$

Answer (score 3):

Alt. hint:   let $\,f\,$ be the [Dirichlet function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nowhere_continuous_function#Dirichlet_function) and $\,x = \sqrt{2}\,$, then the limits are $\,0\,$ and $\,1\,$, respectively.

Comment: +1 Nice example.

Comment: @TheoBendit Thanks. I +1'd yours, too, also because of the `careful` comment.